# Subscribe to several Twitter Streams API with same credentials

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api

Is there any way to open multiple status streams with the same credentials to track several words?

Answer (score 0):

The streaming API is very limited in the number of streams you can open. The idea is to have a single stream feeding you with all the data you need.

To track more than one word, simply provide a comma delimited list of words. They will all be delivered in the same stream. To change words, you will need to open a new stream with the new list of words and close the old stream.

Here's the docs on the track parameter: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods#track

Comment: Yeah, it's one of our solutions, but for our application, we can't apply it. I wonder how TweetDeck and other clients do for their live search column.